# postgres: aggregate function on multiple fields

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, aggregate

My table is:

```
price: numeric, time: timestamp, type: integer
```

i want to group by type and for each group find max price and earliest (by time) price.

from the computational perspective, it's a simple linear / reduce-like operation. but how can it be done in postgres? is there some existing function like that? do i have to create my own aggregate? should i encode two field into one like `$time-$price` and just find minimum from it?

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm.  Postgres doesn't have a `first()` aggregation function, but you can use arrays instead:

```
select type,
       max(price),
       array_agg(price order by time asc)[1] as earliest_price
from t
group by type;
```

EDIT:

There are other approaches, such as:

```
select distinct on (type) type,
       max(price) over (partition by type),
       price
from t
order by type, time asc;
```

Comment: But then the `first()` aggregate is quite easy to implement: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/First/last_(aggregate)

Comment: but this requires O(n) memory, right? in case each type contains a lot of rows, this might require a lot of memory. while, computationally, it can be done in O(1) memory without storing all rows - is it possible in postgres?

Comment: @piotrek . . . Google BigQuery is much nicer.  It supports a `LIMIT` clause in `array_agg()` to avoid that problem.